# How to choose which Build Configuration Xcode 4 will use when building for my device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

Xcode 3 offered to select a Build Configuration prior to building.

In Xcode 4 all I have is this:

RUN [Test | Profile | Analyze], STOP, [AppName > My iPhone]

When clicking and holding the large dropdown button that includes the app name, there are these options only:

- My device
- iPad 4.3 Simulator
- iPhone 4.3 Simulator
- iPad 5.0 Simulator
- iPhone 5.0 Simulator

While developing / debugging (at least intending to do so) Xcode 4 throws warnings that it failed to codesign verification. However, I have codesigning only active for the App Store distribution config. Before I set up that distribution config in the Scheme Editor for "Archive", there was no problem. So I guess Xcode 4 now still uses my distribution config for normal development.

How can I tell Xcode 4 to use my "Debug" configuration when building? Probably I must select a Scheme. But like you can see in the dropdown options list above, there's no way to pick one when building.

Answer (score 9):

Edit your run/build-scheme;

[image]

Make sure the RUN scheme is currently selected and select the appropriate configuration;

[image]

Comment: The "Build" scheme looks very different. There's just one row with these columns: AppName Target | Analyze=ON, Test=ON, Run=ON_grayedOut | Profile=ON_grayedOut | Archive=ON. The Run scheme was already set to Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, "build" is shorthand for "build for run".  The configuration for "Run" is used for the "Build" task, therefore set your configuration in the Run task.